# laravel ajax post request sending json data

Tags: ajax, post, laravel-5.6

making an AJAX post request along with sending JSON data to a laravel controller function.The JSON data being sent is not accessible within controller function.

The JSON data being sent must be accessible within controller is expected

```
 $.ajax({
               headers: {
                     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                url : '/admin/maintenances/afterpayment',
                method : 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                data :  details,
                contentType : "application/json"
            }).done(function(response){
                alert('success   '+JSON.stringify(response));
                window.location = "dispdetails";
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('FAILED! ERROR: ' + errorThrown);
            });  

      });
```

```
     public function afterpayment(Request $request)
{         $response = array('status' => $request->deatails,'url' => '/dispdetails');
           return response( )->json($response);

            }
```

after the successful execution of AJAX post request,it is expected in alert message the response value to be the details data sent in JSON format but it is showing as [object Object] .

Answer (score 1):

Try **json_encode()** method in your laravel controller to convert your data into json format.

```
public function afterpayment(Request $request)
{
    $data = array('status' => $request->deatails,'url' => '/dispdetails');
    $response = json_encode($data);

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending ajax request

```
    // Say it's your request payload
    let details = { name: 'John Doe', city: 'Mumbai', status: 'Payment done'};
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        'url': '/admin/maintenances/afterpayment',
        'type': 'POST',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'data': details,
    }).done(function (response) {
        alert('success: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        // Redirect to response url
        window.location.replace(response.url);
    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOps, error) {
        console.log('Failed: ' + error);
    });
```

In your laravel controller

```
    public function afterpayment(Request $request)
    {
        // Assuming your returning entire request payload
        return response()->json(['status' => $request->all(), 'url' => '/your-redirect-url'], 200);
    }
```